# modal popup handling in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, modalpopup

I have written the below code to handle the popup for OTP.

Actually it is landing the web page and entering the user name and password and clicking on login button, then OTP pop up displays. it is handling all these things, but unable to enter the PIN in popup( i am not sure i am correctly handling this popup) . There are no frames in this.

The page source looks like this popup. Could you please help me in identifying this OTP popup and enter the PIN. I have tried many ways like directly identifying the elements through xpath, cssselector etc.

Here is the code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("URL");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("user@mail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("pass@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnSignIn")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement wb= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/section/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div"));
        wb.sendKeys("1111");
```

The popup:

[image: popup]

Page source:

[image: sources]

Comment: Use "driver.switchTO().alert();" option before entering the pin because i guess it is an alert box.

Comment: Thanks Gautham for quick response, i tried this switch to alert still  not working

Comment: Share HTML so that we can check

Comment: I tried to improve your question by pulling in the two screenshots, but I think you definitely should look into further improving your question. For example: the 2nd screen shot looks like "all text". If so: dont use screen shots, but insert your code as well formatted/indented text. Beyond that, you should read [mcve] and ensure that your input really contains all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

As per HTML code, its not alert and not in frame. You can simply use id or any locator rather than absolute path which you used.

Some times direct sendkeys will not work. First we need to click once in input field and then enter text.

Some times thread.sleep also helps me before entering text.

Comment: Thanks murali, but i worked on the same what you told like directly identifying the elements and click() and then using webElement i am sending keys. It didn't work. The only difference is i have used implicit wait, but after your suggestion i tried thread.sleep. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple html form.

I don't have any java IDE currently installed, but simple example with C#.

```
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("OTP"));
        element.Click();
        element.SendKeys("Text");
```

Shouldn't be a problem to make java analog from this.

Comment: As per your code  i can guess its the same i used in java like 
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("#OTP"));
wb.click();
wb.sendKeys("1111");
I have used this, still didn't work.

Comment: --> By.xpath("#OTP") <-- It is NOT XPATH. Why don't you use By.id ? If you still want Xpath use "//input[@id='OTP']"

Comment: I used the above code as example, i used id, classname, xpath, cssselector too

Comment: Is this page in public access? I want to try

Comment: Yes it is in public access, but couldn't share. its confidential